# why some textures did not load correctly in vedo library in python?

Tags: 3d, vedo

I'm trying to load some .obj files with their texture by vedo lib:

```
from vedo import *
from transparent import *

mesh = Mesh("3d/gol1/raw_model.obj")#load 3d model
mesh.texture("3d/gol1/texture.png")#load texture on 3d mode

plt = Plotter(offscreen=True)
plt += mesh
plt.show().screenshot("hi.png")#save as png
```

but in some cases, like the image below, the texture did not load correctly:
the correct one:
[image]

and we see here the result after loading texture:

[image: loaded in vedo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the line below before laod the mesh oject:

```py
vedo.settings.use_depth_peeling = True
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure why that happens but depth peeling fixes it..:

```py
from vedo import *
settings.use_depth_peeling = True
msh = Mesh("normalized_model.obj").texture("texture.png")
show(msh, axes=1)
```

[image]

Comment: AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'useDepthPeeling'

Comment: it's `settings.use_depth_peeling=True`.